# Python. How can I extract numbers from multiple string lines in a list?

Tags: python-2.7, numbers, extract

I have a five strings there:

```
some_id(s): [111111,222222,

          3333333,          
          4444444,          
          5555555,          
          6666666],
```

How can i extract these numbers in list of strings?

Answer (score 0):

Use the map function (in Python 2.x):
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

```
some_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
string_list = map(str, some_ids)
```

Or in Python 3, you will need to convert the result from map to a list:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

```
string_list = list(map(str, some_ids))
```